Connect to a device on a different subnet

Device 1 is connected to a network with gateway 172.16.96.1 and netmask 255.255.240.0
Device 2 is connected to a network with gateway 172.16.156.1 and netmask 255.255.252.0

Can I ssh from Device 1 into Device 2?
For context: Device 1 is my laptop connected wirelessly and Device 2 is my Raspberry Pi connected through wire. I don't have access to the router and its configuration.

Are you talking about one single router or a tree-like topology (like one of the networks is "nested" under the other)?

@TomYan look at the subnets: they are disjunct and hence can't be nested!

@MarcusMüller By "nested" I wasn't referring to the IP subnets, but how the two network are interconnected physically / semantically. (Like, is it the usual case of having the WAN port of a home router connected to a LAN port of another, or are they two LANs that are connected to some more "proper" / advanced router, or is it some router that for some reasons has its builtin AP segregated from its wired LAN.)


Can I ssh from Device 1 into Device 2?

Yes.
That's what gateways are for – they route packets between subnets; so your two gateways must know how to reach each other and that the whole other subnet can be found that way, or they must each know how to reach another router that knows. I'll assume you having two networks with gateways means that these gateways are 1. connected (as part of the same network themselves) and 2. properly configured. (I have to assume that – otherwise you'd already be lost the moment you said "can't access the configuration".)
This is by no means specific to Linux, it's how IP works.
Now it's entirely possible that the idea of this network configuration was to keep the two subnets separate. In that case, nothing you can do to directly communicate between the two subnets – you'd need some point in a network that both can reach (which probably means the internet) to do the forwarding; in essence, that's what a virtual private network is. You can build such e.g. with ssh tunnels (tunnelling SSH through SSH), or with a wireguard tunnel (or a VPN service based on that, e.g. tailscale).

It is impossible to know without more specific knowledge of the network.
If the network routes the addresses, then, at the IP level, you should be able to reach the other host.
If the router blocks something, or is there is some other network in between, then the answer is probably no.
Because you have no access to the router's configuration, trial and error is probably the only option.
